# Custom markupextension on custom DataTemplate property

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, markup-extensions

I'm wondering if there is a way to use a custom markup extension on a custom property on a type derived from datatemplate?

I need some additional information inside my DataTemplates:

```
public class MyDataTemplate : DataTemplate
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public string TemplateKey { get; set; }

    public object Geometry { get; set; }
}

<MyDataTemplate x:Key="Foo" DataType="{x:Type system:String}" GroupName="Group1"
                Geometry="{telerik:CommonShape ShapeType=RectangleShape}">
    ...
</MyDataTemplate>
```

When I put the `CommonShape` markupextension on the DataType property, everything works.
When I put the `x:Type` markupextension on the Geometry property, everything works, too.

But if I put the custom markupextension on the custom property, I get the error

```
The property 'Geometry' cannot be set as a property element on template.
Only Triggers and Storyboards are allowed as property elements.
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Alex

Edit:
One possible workaround could be to put the values of the markupextension into the resource dictionary and use a StaticResource on the Geometry property - however, I'm not sure if this is possible using xaml?

Comment: Where is custom property declared?

Comment: It's in the `MyDataTemplate` type, which is derived from DataTemplate (see my question).